# How to set the default of `truncate-lines` for dired buffers to `truncate`?

Tags: dired, major-mode, line-truncation

How can I set the default of `truncate-lines` for dired buffers to `truncate`?

I.e. when I open a new dired buffer it should show the directory truncated and not wrapped into the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```el
(defun my-dired-mode-hook ()
  "Custom behaviours for `dired-mode'."
  ;; `truncate-lines' is automatically buffer-local.
  (setq truncate-lines t))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook #'my-dired-mode-hook)
```

Comment: You can add `-local` after `setq` and spare the comment

Comment: Using `setq-local` in the context of setting `truncate-lines` potentially implies that the user has failed to take the time to investigate whether the variable was already buffer-local.  Or worse, it could mean that the user erroneously thought it was a global variable.  Users should be encouraged, in my opinion, to investigate and learn which variables are global and which ones have already been pre-defined as being buffer-local.

Comment: I agree with both Stefan and lawlist :)  I used plain `setq` with a comment for the benefit of the reader, so that they would also learn that some variables are automatically buffer-local, if they were not already aware.

Comment: Thanks for this, @phils. _Side note:_ Because `truncate-lines` is a (buffer-local) variable I can even put `truncate-lines: t` in the `.dired` or `.dir-locals.el` file. :-)

Comment: @halloleo If you use `.dir-locals.el` (or indeed `.dired`, although that is deprecated), then the value is set buffer-locally (by way of  `make-local-variable`) *regardless* of whether or not a plain `setq` would do the same thing.

Comment: i.e. All variables *can* be given a buffer-local value, but some of them (such as `truncate-lines`) also *default* to behaving that way when they are set, rather than only doing it on explicit request.